# Using a favicon.png

Tags: html

I cannot get my facvicon to work. What am I doing wrong? I tried favicon.ico first. No luck. Now I am trying a png.

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png"/>
</head>!
```

[my favicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvlP0.png)

Comment: By the way, remember to accept answers - currently only 48% of your questions have accepted answers. If you do this, then you'll find more people will answer you, and we know not to add more answers for them!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the "best way" is to make an icon in .ico format, call it favicon.ico and place it at your document root (i.e. so it can be accessed by www.example.com/favicon.ico).

If you really don't want to use favicon.ico, you can use:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/custom/file/anything.ico" />
```

Not that IE for some reason used 'shortcut icon' as the attribute, even though it has a space in it!

If this doesn't work, your browser has likely cached things, so do that, then clear your browser cache, and try again.

A good site for making a small .ico file is http://www.favicon.cc/ .

If you don't want to do that, then you can use a png, but it won't work in Internet Explorer. You'll have to use:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

for that to work.

But don't, just use an .ico!

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will simply look for `favicon.ico` in the site root directory and will use this. For older browsers like IE6 it has to be 16x16px but IE6 support is officially dis-continued, so nevermind.

`.ico` supports full alpha and has the 16 million colour palette, so there's not much point in using PNGs. For my site, I made a bunch of icons, all in different sizes (16px, 32px, 48px, 64px, 128px), and then I used the command line utility ICOBundle to compress them into one, multi-resolution icon file.

Apple also has documentation on how to set up iOS compatible icons for adding websites to the home screen. To finish, the `rel` of a favicon should preferably be `"shortcut icon"`.